# Autoscrolling a datalist in an ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have an Aspx page with a panel and a datalist inside it connected to a datasource.
The datalist is showing news from an RSS feed and I have set scroll bars to allow the users to read the hidden once.
This is my code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="270px" ScrollBars="Vertical" Width="790px" BorderStyle="Outset" Direction="LeftToRight">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList3" runat="server" style="text-align: left" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Justify">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" HorizontalAlign="Justify" />
        <EditItemStyle Height="300px" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#XPath("title")%>
            <br />
            <%#XPath("pubDate")%>
            <br />
            <%#XPath("author")%>
            <br />
            <%#XPath("description")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DataList>
</asp:Panel>
```

I am trying to make the news scrolling continuously and if the user goes over the control with the mouse, stop the autoscrolling and give control to the mouse. How can I do something like that? Any reference or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: jQuery could be helpful, or AJAX.  ASP.NET has UpdatePanels with Timers that you could use (though it's not really the "hot" way of doing it anymore).